# is it possible to overriding a parameter within back() function

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization

I have a simple problem here.

Here's my code

1. route

```
Route::post('change-language', 'LanguageController@changeLanguage')->name('changeLanguage')->middleware('localization');
```

2. localization middlewware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('locale') && \App\Language::get('lang')->pluck('lang')->contains(Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->parameter('locale'))) {
            $lang = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->parameter('locale');
            App::setLocale($lang);
            session()->put('locale', $lang);
            return $next($request);
        }elseif(session()->has('locale') && !\App\Language::get('lang')->pluck('lang')->contains(Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->parameter('locale'))){
            $lang = 'id';
            App::setLocale($lang);
            session()->put('locale', $lang);
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

3. changeLanguage functtion

```
public function changeLanguage(Request $req)
    {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

As you can see in localization middleware, I change the language based on the route url. when I change the return of `changeLocalization` something like `return redirect($req->lang)` it work like a charm. but i want to redirect back to previous route. Is it possible to add or overriding the route paramater in back() function ?

Comment: Just call `return back();` it will direct to the intended url in session

Comment: instead of `back()` you can use `return redirect()->route('your route name to which you want to redirect back')`

Comment: thank you for the response, it is returned to the previous route, but it's not change the language

Comment: or you can also use `return redirect()->back()->with(your parameter you want to pass)`

Comment: Do you mean like this?  `return redirect()->back()->with($req->lang);`

Comment: Yes exactly, try it or `return back()->with($req->lang)`

Comment: still it doesn't change the language

Comment: In stead of using `back()` can you recreate the url with same parameter and new values and redirect to that url in stead of using back()